# GAM new local user

Tags: genexus-gam

sorry if this is a very stupid question, I'm really new to Genexus I'm following the online course.

I have a small web application with GAM, I cant find the way to active the option for users to create their own accounts in the login page, is this an option or should I create my own web panel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's an object called `GAMHome`, that's where you need to login to create Roles, Users, logins, etc.

Just Run it from the `Main Programs` category node at the `Folder View` panel